# Reading a video file using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use this sample code to read a video file but everytime I compile I get these errors.

Here's the code:

```
#include "cv.h"   
#include "highgui.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   CvCapture* capture=0;
   IplImage* frame=0;

capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("~/Documents/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.2/samples/c/tree.avi"); // read AVI video


if( !capture )
    throw "Error when reading steam_avi";

cvNamedWindow( "w", 1);

for( ; ; )
{
  /*  int cvGrabFrame (CvCapture* capture);

    IplImage* cvRetrieveFrame (CvCapture* capture)*/

    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

    if(!frame)
        break;

    cvShowImage("w", frame);

}



cvWaitKey(0); // key press to close window

cvDestroyWindow("w");

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

Here is what I compiled with:

```
 g++ CaptureVideo.cpp -o CaptureVideo \-I /usr/local/include/opencv -L /usr/local/lib \-lm -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I get these errors when I compile

```
"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcv"

"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhighgui"

"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcvaux"

"collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"
```

Comment: Try removing the space after '-L'.  Also add "-L" for the `cv, highgui,` and `cvaux` libraries.

Comment: Ok i have done that, now i'm getting this
CaptureVideo.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `cvCreateFileCapture'

CaptureVideo.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `cvNamedWindow'

CaptureVideo.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `cvQueryFrame'

CaptureVideo.cpp:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `cvShowImage'

CaptureVideo.cpp:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'

CaptureVideo.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `cvDestroyWindow'

CaptureVideo.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'

Comment: Add the libraries for `cvCreateFileCapture`, `cvQueryFrame` and `cvWaitKey` or search the web for which OpenCV libraries you need including all dependencies.

Comment: I have tried pretty much all the '#include's that are available but I still get the same problem :(

Comment: I didn't say to include the `#includes`. I said to include the *libraries*. In 'nix land these are usually files called `lib*`, as in `libcv`. The `#includes` only contain information on **how** to use the functions, not the content. The content of the functions is included in a *library*.

Comment: How did you install openCV? Try running `pkg-config opencv --libs` or `pkg-config cv --libs`